# How to share files in a directory over either HTML or REST

Tags: webserver

I've been looking for any premade free file sharing servers or services that can be self-hosted, but I've only come across servers like [ownCloud](https://owncloud.com/), that have way too many features regarding our needs (for example the list provded [here](https://www.tecmint.com/free-open-source-cloud-storage-tools-for-linux/)).

Are there any (HTML server package or REST) based file sharing servers for linux that can do the following:

- Share files in a given directory
- No need for user accounts
- No possibility for people to create accounts
- Ratelimit the downloads

Basically all it has to do is allow any people to download files using their web browser, nothing less nothing more. If the server had REST functionality, it would be better as then we could integrate the server to our website directly

Comment: "integrate the server to our website directly"... what about your existing web server? What about the way it already serves files are you trying to fix?

Comment: @spuck the current website we have is hosted on a different server and by integration i mean that the website could query the contents of the file share server via the REST api

Comment: This is probably lower-level than what you're looking for, but the scp command transfers files very simply, in one line.
You just need to know the ip address you are connecting to and the location of the directory on the server.

Comment: @Nuubles I think you're looking for a plain web server - Apache and Nginx are the popular ones. At the most basic level, you put some files in a directory and the web server exposes those files over HTTP/HTTPS. No authentication or user accounts by default. Rate limiting is a bit more work, but there are definitely options for it.

Comment: Before I post an answer, let me be sure you want what I can offer: </p>  You would like to have read only, anonymous access to a given directory, and access via a URL.  Your rate limiting would be done with iptables. Is this what your expected result is?

Comment: @BeeKay yes, that's exactly what I want

Comment: Take a look at vsftpd.  It should hit all of your requirements.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-anonymous-downloads-on-ubuntu-16-04